# Very simple code, but got error "Activity has been destroyed" when use Fragment 

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent, android-widget

I made a very simple **Activity** which shows a simple **ListFragment** like below:

My Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();

          FirstFragment list = new FirstFragment();
          fragMgr.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
    }

}
```

My ListFragment:

```
public class FirstFragment extends ListFragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        inflater.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        String listContent[] = {"Larry", "Moe", "Curly"}; 
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, listContent));
    }
   ...
}
```

When I start my app, I got **error message**:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
E/AndroidRuntime(  947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
E/AndroidRuntime(  947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
E/AndroidRuntime(  947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(  947):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
E/AndroidRuntime(  947):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  947):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
E/AndroidRuntime(  947):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
...
```

It complains that **Activity has been destroyed**, **Why???**

P.S. main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:paddingLeft="8dp"
  android:paddingRight="8dp">

  <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="next" />

  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:text="No data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 68):

I also faced a similar problem.
I realized that this happened because the activity was being destroyed while the `FragmentTransaction` was about to get `.commit()`.

A solution to this was to check whether the `Activity.isFinishing()` is true or not.

```
if (!isFinishing()) {
  FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
     .beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(SOME_RES_ID, myFragmentInstance);
  ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me! Came here through a [discussion over Github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/1031). Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 36):

I figured out myself, It is because I missed the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in my Activity onCreate() method . After added this, things are fine.

Comment: If some one can explain the deep reason, I will accept the better one not mine :)

Comment: In my case I was calling super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); after adding the fragment.

Comment: @lemm.fin I was going through this article and found its explained quite well over there. https://medium.com/@elye.project/handling-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-d4ee8b630066

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same issue and unable to fix it.
Event I added isFinishing() check as well. but no luck.

then I added one more check **isDestroyed**() and its working fine now.

```
if (!isFinishing() && !isDestroyed()) {
  FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
     .beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(LAYOUT_ID, myFragmentInstance);
  ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: Note that `onDestroyed()` was added in API level 17.

Answer (score 4):

To give an explanation:

The framework creates the `Activity` and calls `Activity.onCreate()`.

`Activity.onCreate()` will somehow attach to the `FragmentManager` to let it know about the hosting activity. `Activity.onDestroy()` will unregister it again.

Now, you extend `Activity` and override `onCreate()`. You make calls to `FragmentManager` without calling through to`Activity.onCreate()`. The whole registration logic explained above is not executed. The `FragmentManager` therefore does not know anything about the activity and assumes it has already been destroyed and generates the exception with the misleading error message.

Answer (score 3):

Just to make sure I'm seeing this right, MyActivity is the activity that you're trying to launch and then add an instance of FirstFragment into, right?

Immediately I see two things that you need to look at

1) In your activity you never call setContentView() or super.onCreate().  The first call could be a huge issue for you because that means that your layout was never inflated, and therefore, the R variable doesn't exist

2) Your MyActivity needs to have its own xml layout file, which it doesn't have.

Comment: Hi, I don't think an Activity must have a layout file, for example, my code is working after I added super.onCreate(...), my Activity just hosts a Fragment, and the Fragment will inflate a layout to show, not the Activity.

Comment: It's possible since I haven't really used the support package much.  Most of my development is on Honeycomb using multi-pane layouts.  I was just looking at the API docs and I think you're right.  Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: No problem, I am also new to the support package, I start to learn the fragment just from today :)

Answer (score 1):

what i did is immediately after commit i call

`fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();`

and never try to commit after `onpause()` called

Read this Artical [Fragment Transactions & Activity State Loss](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)

Answer (score 1):

Still bad, because got error “Activity has been destroyed”

```
ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

So my solution is add check `if (!isFinishing()&&!isDestroyed())`

```
 if (!isFinishing()&&!isDestroyed()) {
                        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) will call onCreate method in FragmentActivity, which will call `mFragments.attachHost(null /*parent*/);`

This sentence will assign a value to `mHost` in FragmentController, when you calls FragmentTransaction.commit() ,

In the method `enqueueAction()`,it has this sentences

```
 if (mDestroyed || mHost == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Activity has been destroyed");
 }
```

So if you haven't call super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) before you commit a fragmentTransaction, you will get this exception because mHost is null

Answer (score 0):

If any one come across similar type of issue:

I was facing same time of issue, but in my case from Main Activity I was calling to Fragment1 and then if user click on Fragment1 Layout I want to launch another Fragment2 Layout.

I was able to launch Fragment1 from Main activity but Fragment1 to Fragment2 it was failing with exception as **"Activity has been destroyed"** .

I resolved above issue by maintaining FragmentManager object as static in MainActivity class.
 private static FragmentManager mfragmentManager = null;

calling to both fragment using same above object, resolved my issue.

Below is my Fragment switching code from Main Activity.

```
public void switchToFragment(String fragmentName){
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (fragmentName) {
            case "Fragment1":{
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
            }
            case "Fragment2": {
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
            }
        }

        FragmentTransaction transaction = mfragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```