# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState while using FragmentTabHost

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragment-tab-host

I am trying create a tabbed activity using the below code

```
public class FragmentTabs extends FragmentActivity {

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
            SimpleFrag.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("detailed").setIndicator("Detailed"),
            DetailedFrag.class, null);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

The code always shows 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` inside FragmentManager. I googled seveal times and goes through almos all the links. but i can't get any solution. Please help me because i'm stuck on this.

------------------------------------------------------Edit---------------------------------

The above code working fine sometimes and throws exception sometimes.

Comment: you can try this,it solves my problem
[Very simple code, but got error “Activity has been destroyed” when use Fragment][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132027/very-simple-code-but-got-error-activity-has-been-destroyed-when-use-fragment/16995117#16995117

Answer (score 1):

please try the following code.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
View root = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
setContentView(root);
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) root.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),SimpleFrag.class, null);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("detailed").setIndicator("Detailed"), DetailedFrag.class, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // write code here
    }
```

if not convey the code