# Android Fragment - Runtime Exception - Activity has been destroy

Tags: android, class, android-activity, fragment

I start in my MainActivity about

```
OSMdroidFragment Map = new OSMdroidFragment();
Map.setFragment();
```

a new class. The method setFragment start a other class with my frag.

```
public class OSMdroidFragment extends MainActivity
{
    void setFragment() 
    {
        map = true;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        MapFragment frag = new MapFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_view, frag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    public class MapFragment extends Fragment
    {
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            View mainView       = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainview, container, false);
```

after the command `fragmentTransaction.commit();` i got the error:

```
06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thomas_smart/com.example.thomas_smart.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
```

I dont know what i can do. I have only found this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132027/very-simple-code-but-got-error-activity-has-been-destroyed-when-use-fragment) ... somebody a idea?

Here is the complete error list:

```
06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thomas_smart/com.example.thomas_smart.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1295)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:548)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:532)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at com.example.thomas_smart.OSMdroidFragment.setFragment(OSMdroidFragment.java:49)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at com.example.thomas_smart.MainActivity.selectDrawerItem(MainActivity.java:361)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at com.example.thomas_smart.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:303)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)

06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
06-19 16:34:33.661: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     ... 11 more
```

I have found a new error message :

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.thomas_smart/com.example.thomas_smart.OSMdroidFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I have to create a new Activity in the manifest? i dont want to start a new activity ...

Comment: Can you post your entire error list? That will help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making your activity extend `FragmentActivity` instead!

Also, try using `fragmentTransaction.add(...)` method!

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Yes, this will work. But i need the extends MainActivity for all my variables and objects.

Comment: Does MainActivity extend FragmentActivity?

Comment: No, that does not change the problem ... it must be a problem with the activity ...