# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState WHEN commit

Tags: android

I have got exception when `ft.commit()` and I don't know why.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1448)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1466)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:634)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:613)
    at MainActivity.attachFragment(MainActivity.java:242)
    at MainActivity.attachFragment(MainActivity.java:225)
    at MainActivity.showHome(MainActivity.java:171)
    at MainActivity.onComplete(MainActivity.java:278)
    at MDownloadManager.onDownloadComplete(MDownloadManager.java:83)
    at DownloadRequestQueue$CallBackDelivery$2.run(DownloadRequestQueue.java:61)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Here is my method where crash is comming.

```
FragmentManager     fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

if(addToBackStack) {
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment, tag);
} else {
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, tag);
}

ft.commit();
```

Have you got any idea what is wrong?

I don't use `onSaveInstanceState` in my project.

Comment: I think this answer is more efficient to any code. Check the link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16995117/7806873

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Complete solution at [Solution for IllegalStateException](https://androidclarified.wordpress.com/2018/06/13/illegalstateexception-cannot-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate/)

Overriding onSaveInstanceSate is a hack which doesnt necessarily work for all the scenerios. Also using commitAllowingStateLoss() is dangerous and could lead to UI irregularities.

We need to understand that IllegalStateException is encountered when we try to commit a fragment after the Activity state is lost - Activity is not in foreground (to understand more about Activity states [read this](https://androidclarified.wordpress.com/2018/06/13/illegalstateexception-cannot-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate/)). Therefore to avoid (resolve) this exception we just delay our fragment transaction until the state is restored

Declare two private boolean variables

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Boolean variable to mark if the transaction is safe
    private boolean isTransactionSafe;

    //Boolean variable to mark if there is any transaction pending
    private boolean isTransactionPending;
```

Now in onPostResume() and onPause we set and unset our boolean variable isTransactionSafe. Idea is to mark trasnsaction safe only when the activity is in foreground so there is no chance of stateloss.

```
/*
onPostResume is called only when the activity's state is completely restored. In this we will
set our boolean variable to true. Indicating that transaction is safe now
 */
public void onPostResume(){
    super.onPostResume();
    isTransactionSafe=true;
}
/*
onPause is called just before the activity moves to background and also before onSaveInstanceState. In this
we will mark the transaction as unsafe
 */

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    isTransactionSafe=false;

}

private void commitFragment(){
    if(isTransactionSafe) {
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, myFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

What we have done so far will save from IllegalStateException but our transactions will be lost if they are done after the activity moves to background, kind of like commitAllowStateloss(). To help with that we have isTransactionPending boolean variable

```
public void onPostResume(){
   super.onPostResume();
   isTransactionSafe=true;
/* Here after the activity is restored we check if there is any transaction pending from
the last restoration
*/
   if (isTransactionPending) {
      commitFragment();
   }
}


private void commitFragment(){

 if(isTransactionSafe) {
     MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, myFragment);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
     isTransactionPending=false;
 }else {
     /*
     If any transaction is not done because the activity is in background. We set the
     isTransactionPending variable to true so that we can pick this up when we come back to
foreground
     */
     isTransactionPending=true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Good one IrshadKumail.

Comment: Thanks @IsaacKingston

Answer (score 1):

The `onSaveInstanceState` method is part of the activity lifecycle. So, even if you don't call it explicitly, it is call at some point by your Activity.

So the question is where in the activity lifecycle did you use the code you show us ?
One workaround is to use [commitAllowingStateLoss](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitAllowingStateLoss%28%29) instead of commit for the fragment transaction.

(You should read the description in the link to see if it is ok for you to use this method)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but I was able to solve this by overriding onSaveInstanceState and comment the line of calling its super like this in fragment.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
 //   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Hope that help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated solution using **Kotlin**. For full details you can check this article : [Avoid Fragment IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState](https://medium.com/@113408/avoid-fragment-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-ba76ae4f00fe)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
private var isActivityResumed = false
private var lastCall: (() -> Unit)? = null

companion object {
    private const val ROOT_FRAGMENT = "root"
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //Call some expensive async operation that will result in onRequestCallback below
    myExpensiveAsyncOperation()
}
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    //Very important flag
    isActivityResumed = false
}
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    isActivityResumed = true
    //If we have some fragment to show do it now then clear the queue           
    if(lastCall != null){
        updateView(lastCall!!)
        lastCall = null
    }
}
/**
 * Fragment Management
 */
private val fragmentA : () -> Unit = {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer_fl, FragmentA())
        .addToBackStack(ROOT_FRAGMENT)
        .commit()
}

private val fragmentB : () -> Unit = {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer_fl, FragmentB())
        .addToBackStack(ROOT_FRAGMENT)
        .commit()
}

private val popToRoot : () -> Unit = { supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(ROOT_FRAGMENT,0) }
// The function responsible for all our transactions
private fun updateView(action: () -> Unit){
    //If the activity is in background we register the transaction
    if(!isActivityResumed){
        lastCall = action
    } else {
    //Else we just invoke it
        action.invoke()
    }
}
// Just an example
private fun onRequestCallback() {
    if(something) {
        updateView(fragmentA)
    else {
        updateView(fragmentB)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, you cannot commit fragment transactions in an activity after `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` has been called. When is your code being called?

`onSavedInstanceState` is called as part of the activity lifecycle when a configuration change occurs. You have no control over it.

Answer (score 0):

> Hope this will help

**EDIT1:** after some more research, this is a known [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19917) in the support package.

If you need to save the instance, and add something to your `outState` `Bundle` you can use the following :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_KEY", "WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_VALUE");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

**EDIT2:** this may also occur if you are trying to perform a transaction after your `Activity` is gone in background. To avoid this you should use `commitAllowingStateLoss()`

**EDIT3:** The above solutions were fixing issues in the early support.v4 libraries from what I can remember. But if you still have issues with this you **MUST** also read [@AlexLockwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/844882/alex-lockwood) 's blog : [Fragment Transactions & Activity State Loss](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)

Summary from the blog post (but I strongly recommend you to read it) :

- **NEVER** `commit()` transactions after `onPause()` on pre-Honeycomb, and `onStop()` on post-Honeycomb
- Be careful when committing transactions inside `Activity` lifecycle methods. **Use** `onCreate()`, `onResumeFragments()` and `onPostResume()`
- Avoid performing transactions inside asynchronous callback methods
- Use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` only as a last resort

Answer (score 0):

If you are using coroutines in your project you can easily make sure that your code will runs when lifecycle state is at least Started and not destroyed.

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted{}
```